# Why my static variables' values change every time I call?

Tags: java, static, static-methods, static-members

Every time I call getIndex static method of MyClass prints "Index: 1" to screen. I want to increase or decrease index's value. What is wrong with my code?

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public static int index=0;

    public static void getIndex()
    {
       index++;
       System.out.println("Index:"+index);
       if(index>10)
            index=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not increment the value of `index` in the getter, in fact is odd to modify a field in a getter method. IMO you should not have it as `static` field, `getIndex` method should not be static as well.

Comment: `getIndex();getIndex();getIndex();` it prints 1,2,3. umm... I am confused.

Comment: Make `index` `private` and recompile your code, to detect accidental modification by client code.

Comment: How do you use getIndex() from the main program?

Comment: How do you call the method multiple times?

Comment: did you recompile MyClass?  are you using the latest compiled version?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The indication is that this code was written to experiment and learn about the behavior of the language, so in that case there's nothing wrong with a static incrementing getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I add code to call your example it works as you expect:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public static int index=0;

    public static void getIndex()
    {
       index++;
       System.out.println("Index:"+index);
       if(index>10)
            index=0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            getIndex();
        }
    }
}
```

printing:

```
Index:1
Index:2
Index:3
Index:4
Index:5
Index:6
Index:7
Index:8
Index:9
Index:10
Index:11
Index:1
```

to the console. So how you're calling this must be the problem.

Comment: yes, problem is how I am calling the method.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A guess: you're calling `getIndex()` only once in the program, but then running the program several times. That won't work; variable values aren't preserved across instances of the program. Each time you start the program, `index` is reset to 0. Call `getIndex()` multiple times within a single run of the program, and you will see it increment as you expect.